# Design Time null reference error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in my WPF application I refer to a selected value of a combobox with

```
{Binding Source={x:Reference myComboBox} ,Path=SelectedItem}
```

I do this inside of DataGrid Columns.

This is throwing a null reference exception at design time (not run time). Is there any way to fix this, or can I access the selected Item somehow other than that?

ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox         x:Name="myComboBox"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                   />
```

DataGridTextColumn:

```
<DataGridTextColumn HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource myStyle}"  Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Reference myComboBox} ,Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ConvertSomething}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource Something}}" Header="MyHeader " Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=MyBindingName}" />
```

Comment: Can you post the full code..?

Comment: @NullReferenceException I hope this is enough.

Comment: What a version of `VisaulStudio` are you using?

Comment: 2013 Premium with Update 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case try using [`proxy`](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) of Freezable type, that inherit `DataContext`. Now we do not need to refer to `ComboBox` because we will have a property that is in `DataContext`. I think, this is a more universal solution:

**`BindingProxy`**

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get 
        {
            return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); 
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(DataProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data",
                                                                                typeof(object),
                                                                                typeof(BindingProxy));
}
```

**`XAML`**

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:BindingProxy x:Key="bindingProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem, 
                                                 Converter={StaticResource ConvertSomething}, 
                                                 ConverterParameter={StaticResource Something}}" 
                                                 Source={StaticResource bindingProxy}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not try `{Binding ElementName=myComboBox ,Path=SelectedItem}`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it will not work, because `DataGridColumns` not located in the VisualTree of `DataGrid`.