# Binding using Source and x:Reference leads to design-time error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

for our WPF application I have designed a CustomControl to mimic some flyout-like behavior. The flyout basically just consists of a `FrameworkElement` which holds the content that is placed inside the flyout.

Controls that are placed in the `FrameworkElement` of the flyout are, of course, bound to other controls. However, I am confused as this results in several problems:

1. I can not use `ElementName=sourceName` to set the source of the binding. Instead I have to use `Source={x:Reference sourceName}` to denote the source.
2. The XAML editor of VisualStudio marks all lines where a binding of this type occurs and the ErrorList shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for each occurrence of the binding (no exception is thrown within the designer view).

The project builds successfully and during runtime all bindings work flawlessly! Besides that, it does not matter if the flyout is implemented as a UserControl or a CustomControl.

If a control that is not placed in the flyout is bound to the same source I can use `ElementName=sourceName` without any problems and the correct values are displayed in the designer.
As proposed in some other replies concerning this error I tried to attach the VS instance to the debugger of a second instance of VS but no errors/exceptions are displayed there.

As already mentioned, everything works at runtime. However, as multiple developers are working on this project it is not acceptable to have any errors at all; warnings would be acceptable to a certain extend.

We know that using a binding proxy (like it is proposed in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22531679/119177) should/could solve the problem. However, because the current binding is actually working, we hope to solve the design-time problem some other way (maybe even with just suppressing the error message).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could submit this as an error report to Microsoft

Comment: It would be useful to see the code for the flyout and an example of how you've placed it in your XAML. Could you also post which framework version you're targeting?